# strtok and strncat error

Tags: c, string, strtok, strcat

I want to add string "ay" to each word by using both strtok and strncat. But there seemed to be a conflict somewhere that I cannot find. It only gives me the first word "Computeray" for an output. Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Computer science is hard";
    char* Token;
    char* work = "ay";
    Token = strtok(str, " ");

    while (Token != NULL)
    {
        strncat(Token, work, 2);
        printf("%s", Token);
        Token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the string (with `strcat`) and expecting `strtok` to still behave properly - that's not going to work.  Instead of using `strcat`, just print the `"ay"` separately:

```
while (Token != NULL)
{
    printf("%say ", Token);
    Token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Even if it were working the way you'd like, you'd be overwriting a bunch of your input along the way.  Probably not what you were going for - if you need to build up a whole new string, you should do it into a new buffer, instead of overwriting the input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, how do I print "ay" at the end in each word without using strncat/strcat then?

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Carl provided an excellent example, `printf("%say ", Token)`.

Comment: @cnicutar Oh nvm didn't catch that first. Thanks to you